# Can't modify directory contents where I am part of owner's group

Tags: linux, permissions

I am not able to create or delete files inside a directory which has `www-data` as owner and has relevant permissions as far as I can see:

```
ankblog$ ll
total 88
drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data www-data  4096 May 28 06:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 ankush   ankush    4096 May 28 06:56 ../
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 May 28 05:06 ankblog/
srwxrwxrwx 1 root     root         0 May 28 06:55 ankblog.sock=
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   197 May 28 06:30 ankblog_uwsgi.ini*
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data  4096 May 28 04:07 blog/
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 May 27 18:11 env/
drwxrwxr-x 8 www-data www-data  4096 May 28 06:58 .git/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data    94 May 28 06:32 .gitignore*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 35141 May 27 18:10 LICENSE*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   250 May 28 04:51 manage.py*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   637 May 27 18:10 README.md*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data    31 May 27 18:10 requirements.txt*
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 May 28 05:06 static/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   663 May 28 04:55 uwsgi_params*
```

. . .

```
ankblog$ whoami
ankush
```

. . .

```
ankblog$ sudo useradd -g www-data ankush
useradd: user 'ankush' already exists
```

. . .

```
ankblog$ sudo useradd -G www-data ankush
useradd: user 'ankush' already exists
```

. . .

```
ankblog$ touch file
touch: cannot touch ‘file’: Permission denied
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather want to use

```
usermod -g www-data ankush
```

as error messages pointed out, for once clearly(*), user ankush already exists.

The command useradd do not **add** user to group, but **create** user.

(*) this is not always the cases in unix/linux world.

you might have a look at man page from usermod and useradd.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the error message meant that the user already existed in that group. ^.^ Since I keep messing around a lot on my machine, I thought maybe I'd added myself to this group before.